# How to pass comma separated values from yacc to cpp file node

Tags: compilers

I am writing a compiler in CPP using Flex and Bison and having trouble understanding passing values up the syntax tree in bison.
I have grammar like this below,  'exp' would evaluate to any number.

```
args_list: exp | args_list comma exp; 
array_list: datatype identifier '[' number']' equal '{' args_list'}'{$$ = new array_node($1, $2, $4, $8);}
```

I wanted to pass args_list to the array_node but not getting how to pass? As you can see user can initialize array with any length but how to pass this list to CPP node?
for example - int a[4] = {1,2,3,4} ; I want to pass something like

```
new array_node(datatype, a, number, args_list)
```

in which I am not getting how to pass args_list so that I can have array type.
Or please suggest me another way to pass the array list to the cpp file. or how to pass whole array to cpp file from yacc?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. [Questions about how a particular piece of software or hardware works aren't science.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (When asking an appropriate audience (check out [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), try and pinpoint what about the code presented doesn't work as specified - I think it looks promising.)

Answer (score 0):

args_list’s type can be vector.
Then, instead of calling to new array_node you can have a factory method (array_node::factory) which parses the type, casts the args and returns the array_node object

Comment: I understood that my array_node constructor will have one formal parameter of vector type, but from yacc file how to send these numbers? like {2, 4, 5, 7} as user may enter as many numbers as he want. and from yacc will this be considered as string? or I can not send each numbers position with $1, $2 and so one

Comment: You can store them in a vector of strings and  later convert them or you can put a mid rule action after the type declaration and save the type in a global variable or save it as one of the array's attributes and args_list will look up for it  (however you will need to change your rules)